# PHP Removing attributes from <a> specifically when getting Facebook JSon

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

i'm pulling a facebook posts page using:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11')));
$facebook = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=XXXXXXXXXX&format=json', true, $context);

$facebook = json_decode($facebook,true);
```

but i get the crap onclicks, mouseovers, rels etc stuff coming through on the  tag.

Whats the best way to just remove the a tag attributes except for href and perhaps the target attribute using php?

thanks
Andy

Comment: Feed it to DOM, and extract just the attributes you want, building a new tags as you go.

Answer (score 0):

[PREG_MATCH](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)  is a great starting point.  I am sure there are some premade classes that will strip that out for you though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a foreach-loop and use PREG_MATCH to get rid of unwanted onclicks.